# Efficient method for a grid of clickable images in wxPython?

Tags: python, image, performance, wxpython

Which is the most efficient method to display a grid of about 1000 clickable images in wxPython ?

Currently i am using a `GridSizer` filled with `StaticBitmap` objects. But its quite slow for 500+ images.

One more thing is that, i have a listbox of categories on the left. That is to filter the images. Categories will be like "All", "Cat 1", "Cat 2" etc. When i click "All", all the image have to be displayed.

How i am doing this currently :

- A VERTICAL `BoxSizer` will contain n
  `GridSizer` objects, one for each
  category. I add the `StaticBitmap`
  objects to multiple GridSizers
  depending on the categories it
  belongs to.
- Then i display only that    GridSizer
  depending on which category    is
  selected

This method is also terribly slow for anything over 300 images. So, how do i achieve the same effect efficiently ?

.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that not all 1000 images are onscreen at the same time, correct? If so, you should be able to just load up the number you need and when the user scrolls, load up the next set as needed. I think the people on the wxPython list usually used DCs to blit their images onscreen or they use the FloatCanvas widget. I would recommend asking over on their list where there are a number of experts on drawing images onscreen: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wxpython-users

Comment: Wouldn't drawing on scroll be a bit of an overkill ? If the user scrolls too fast, there will be a very obvious lag, no ? And yeah, i have posted it on the wxpython-users group now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think a ListCtrl in ICON style would be the best way to do this.

If you look at the wxPython Demos, the UltimateListCtrl sample in the wx.LC_ICON style is a good example of what you could create.

Comment: This seems to be a good idea. I've not worked with ListCtrl before. Could you point me to a tutorial to get started ? I couldn't find the UltimateListCtrl sample either.

Comment: I implemented this using `ListCtrl` and the time required the build the list initially reduced considerably than with `StaticBitmaps`. But, when i click on the categories, the time require to rebuild the ListCtrl is more than the StaticBitmap method. Is there any way to filter a ListCtrl without rebuilding it all over again ?

Comment: How are you rebuilding the ListCtrl? Perhaps you should add and remove only the items that are changing when the user selects different categories.